# controlling 3 relays with 1 signal wire

Tags: relay, multiplexer

my goal is to create circuit which would be able to trigger one of 3 +12v relays (only 1 relay could be active at once). Thinking to use 3 switches and mux41 with demux to send encoded signal through 1 wire.

If i'm right, by default output is first input value, if control wires AB(s1.s0) = 01, then output has 2nd input value? So to get AB=01 (s1,s0) I would need to give 0volts to A pin and +12 to the B pin? 0 = no voltage, 1 = voltage if im correct?

Im not gonna be using arduino or rpi.

[image]

Comment: how about pulse-width modulation? 1millisec pulse for relay#1, 2millisec puse for relay#2, etc. And use the 74LS123 retriggerable oneshot, several of them, set at 1.5 and 2.5 milliSec, to provide time-discrimination. or 1 volt, 2volt, and 3 volt pulses, with quad analog comparator.

Comment: I think you have the cart before the horse. You need to determine what these "encoded signals" will look like before worrying about how to get them onto the wire.

Answer (score 3):

Satellite dish receiver LNB units do exactly this by sensing the  DC bias voltage on the coax line. This approach could be adapted for your purpose.

This would require two comparators and some simple gating. It would work as follows.

Set the comparators at Vth(1) and Vth(2). Assume Vth(1) is less than Vth(2). Vbias is the control voltage. Then:

```
Vbias < Vth(1): Turn on Relay 1
Vbias > Vth(1) and < Vth(2): Turn on Relay 2
Vbias > Vth(2): Turn on Relay 3
```

If you need the 4th state of all relays off, add another comparator, set to Vth(0) some value less than Vth(1). The table becomes then:

```
Vbias < Vth(0): all off
Vbias > Vth(0) and < Vth(1): Turn on Relay 1
Vbias > Vth(1) and < Vth(2): Turn on Relay 2
Vbias > Vth(2): Turn on Relay 3
```

There are specialty chips for satellite set-tops to make the bias voltage, but in your case a simple LDO with a couple of settings should do it.

Comment: This is how I'd do it, but I'd use every day op-amps or comparators set up as three window comparators. No specialized or fancy chips needed

Answer (score 2):

You could use 3 different voltages (0, VCC, half-way) and decode using window comparators. A quad op-amp and a few resistors would do. plus of course the relay drivers. (Use a 4th level if you need the all-off option)

Do you need 1 of 3 or 1 of 4 (including all relays off)? For 1 of 3: have the signal wire at either 0, +VCC or -VCC. Use diodes to let +VCC activeate one relay, -VCC the other, and arrange for neither-activated to activate the 3d relay.

Comment: OP wants to be able to trigger one of three relays so you need to detect four input levels, in Vin/4 steps. I'd have posted the same solution as you, will upvote if you revise your answer to primarily describe the 4-state solution.